# Oracle insert NCLOB data into NVARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, insert, nclob

I am tyring to insert NCLOB data into NVARCHAR2.it is showing error ORA - 06512 in stored procedure.

How to fix this error?.

Comment: Please show us your code and the real error. ORA-06512 is just "Error at line ..." which does not mean anything for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share much information so it is difficult to guess what you did and why Oracle complained about it. Though, would `TO_NCHAR` do any good?

> TO_NCHAR (character) converts a character string, CHAR, VARCHAR2, CLOB, or NCLOB value to the national character set. The value returned is always NVARCHAR2

```
SQL> create table test (col_nclob nclob);

Table created.

SQL> create table test2 (col_nvarchar2 nvarchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('x');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test2 (col_nvarchar2)
  2    select to_nchar(t.col_nclob) from test t;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.